# Python Comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've got a list of tuples, each tuple looks like (i,x).

- i = index
- x = value

I need to return a new list (using a comprehension only) that each value will be in the "right" index. If index is missing, we'll put the value -1000 to fill the gap.

**For example:**

Input: `[(4,9), (0,2), (1,4), (3,2)]`
Output should be: `[2, 4, -1000, 2, 9]`

I was trying to use index function, I'm trying to get the index of the tuple `(1,2)`, while I "know" only the first element, the second can be anything.
I want to get the index of the tuple `(1,2)` by search `(1,___)`, is that possible?

- ___ is a positive integer

```
    return [sorted(L)[sorted(L).index((i,))][1] if i in [sorted(L)[j][0] for j in range(0,len(L))] else -1000 for i in range(sorted(L)[len(L)-1][0]+1)]
```

- I can use list/dict/set comprehension, single line.

Thank you all for help!

Comment: Why do you necessarily need comprehension only?\

Comment: Why do you need the index? You just need to know if the current index of the iteration is in the first element of any of the tuples. `t[1] if i in {t[0] for t in tuples)} else 1000`

Comment: I know, But I can't figure out how to write it in a runnable comprehension (this is my lecturer orders... of course it's simpler to do it with two for loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a dictionary that maps indices to values, so we can easily and efficiently get the value for an index:

```
[g(i, -1000) for g in [dict(L).get] for i in range(max(L)[0] + 1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYkxDsIwEAT7vGLLO3GgM0kBBT/IDywXEQRzBY5luYDXm5hqNDP5W19bGi@5tDbjBk@TXFlAKucOJ1PHuFsYhlwsVfKRTHB0qsp4bgURluAfdq808ymuNfyz9VyWFFd6L599eQ04wHHg1n4)